# Cache in gitlab ci while building docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-build

I am building CI/CD pipline with GitLab using GCP cloud build docker image but the **build** is taking longer time to complete
can anyone help me regarding this why build is taking longer time?
How we can reducing the build time i am already using **--cache-from**
Here is my cloudbuild.yaml file
[image: cloudbuild.yaml]